# Files Affected By Command

Tags: command-line, file-comparison

Is there a way to know which files are affected by any command that's entered in terminal? For instance, we all know what `passwd` command does, and which file it affects. But is there a definite way to know the exact file name any command affects?

I have a command that adds user to a file, which implements some policies on those users. But I'm not sure which file it adds to.

Comment: "strace with the option to follow child processes" seems like a reasonable approach to me, @bbb31; you could narrow the field by restricting the view to "open"d files

Answer (score 5):

You can do this rudimentarily by doing `strace -e open <cmd>`; there is also the `-f` option to follow child processes; the `strace` method is not very user friendly (you need to basically understand some C, syscalls, etc) and doesn't work long term. There are other tools like `sysdig` that may work (haven't used it for this purpose). You can run `auditd` or a file based IDS such as AIDE and have it detect when certain files are being changed.

In your question I can't tell if you're asking how to figure out which files a program accesses (i.e. an audit) or if you are trying to alert based on certain files being access (an IDS). If you are trying to figure out which files a program accesses, the best way to do so is to read the source; tools like `strace` are low level.